# JavaScript alert "the page says"

Tags: javascript, alert

I have a form and I am using JavaScript to validate the form, so if we leave a field blank it will alert "Please Enter your Name".

If I go to the link directly, it works perfectly. But I am using an iFrame to embed it into other sites. When I embed it, and click Submit with an empty field it says:

> The page at http://www.domain.com says: Please Enter your name

Comment: I would swap the alerts for a placeholder for your error messages. This way at least things look consistent, less invasive and cleaner

Answer (score 5):

This is a security measure to prevent a framed site from displaying a message that appears to come from the parent site.

You cannot avoid it without avoiding the use of `alert()`.

You could display the information to the user by modifying the DOM to display it as part of the page instead.